# Geoserver interpolation parameters

Tags: interpolation, geoserver

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>USA states population</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>population</Name>
      <Title>Population in the United States</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample filter that filters the United States into three
          categories of population, drawn in different colors</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>&lt; 2M</Title>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">
                <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
                  <!-- Property to transform -->
                  <ogc:PropertyName>t_p</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <!-- Mapping curve definition pairs (input, output) -->
                  <ogc:Function name="env">
                    <ogc:Literal>interval1</ogc:Literal>
                    <ogc:Literal>685430</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
                  <ogc:Function name="env">
                    <ogc:Literal>color1</ogc:Literal>
                    <ogc:Literal>#06E852</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
                  <ogc:Function name="env">
                    <ogc:Literal>interval2</ogc:Literal>
                    <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
                  <ogc:Function name="env">
                    <ogc:Literal>color2</ogc:Literal>
                    <ogc:Literal>#FF0303</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
                  <!-- Interpolation method -->
                  <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
                  <!-- Interpolation mode - defaults to linear -->
                </ogc:Function>
              </CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Boundary</Title>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>label</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>3</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">14</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
                <AnchorPoint>
                  <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                  <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The SLD of my layer looks something like this in which i have given two variables `minpop` and `maxpop` in form of two ogc functions.
In this SLD I am giving values to the variables and those values are taken as parameters in ogc function, but it seems like the ogc function is not working properly.

I have tried not enclosing the env in the literal but the color are still not working? Can you please point out the mistakes in the above SLD?

Comment: can you show us exactly how you write the SLD that doesn't work? and describe exactly what happens when you do that, especially with and with out env values provided in the request. Finally, turn the logging level up to GeoTools Dev and add the **relevant** part of the log file where the mapping fails.

Comment: my SLD looks like this :- <PolygonSymbolizer>
             <Fill>
     <CssParameter name="fill">
       <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
         <!-- Property to transform -->
         <ogc:PropertyName>POP</ogc:PropertyName>

         <!-- Mapping curve definition pairs (input, output) -->
         <ogc:Literal><ogc:Fu <!-- Interpolation method -->
         <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>

         <!-- Interpolation mode - defaults to linear -->
       </ogc:Function>
     </CssParameter>
   </Fill>     
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

Comment: can you provide me an example ?

Comment: can you **edit** the question

Comment: i have edited the sld in the question @Ian Turton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enclosing your function in a `<Literal>` block you are asking GeoServer to use that as text. Your XML should look like:

```
<Fill>
  <CssParameter name="fill">
    <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
      <!-- Property to transform -->
      <ogc:PropertyName>POP</ogc:PropertyName>
      <!-- Mapping curve definition pairs (input, output) -->
      <ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>minpop</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>64000</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function> 
      <ogc:Literal>#06E852</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>maxpop</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>100000000</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function> 
      <ogc:Literal>#FF0303</ogc:Literal> 
      <!-- Interpolation method -->
      <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
      <!-- Interpolation mode - defaults to linear -->
    </ogc:Function>
  </CssParameter> 
</Fill>
```

Comment: what i should add in the above sld to customize the color also?

Comment: please ask a new question, it is hard to see what you have changed above

Comment: done here's the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984301/geoserver-interpolation-color-parameters